# Why does the @mention for a DevOps group work for Pull Requests but not on Work Items?

Tags: azure, usergroups, mention, on-premises-instances

We have an on-prem version of Azure Devops 2020 (Update 1.2).  We have created a group in DevOps for a project, and doing an @mention on any Pull Request discussion works as expected.

The issue seems to be on the Work Items.  When you do an @mention on the discussion section of a work-item, individual users appear and work fine, but the group name doesn't even show up in the "finder".

I am trying to decide if this is a project setting within DevOps or if it has to do with the fact that all of the individual users are loaded from AD, where the group is not . . . but then the issue with it actually working on Pull Requests kind of negates the latter of those two.

Any suggestions or solutions would be appreciated.